# Show actual thumbnail of the category page with the ID with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories, shortcode

i need some help on wordpress

I have to show the thumbnail of my category product of my current category page

So for that i use :

`[product_categories ids='116']`
It's display the cat id 116.

But i'm blocked for the next thing. Get the id of the current page instead of writing it manually.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can get the category ID using the below code

```
$category = get_queried_object();
$cat_id = $category->term_id;
echo $cat_id;
```

You can use this ID and do the rest of things.

Answer (score 0):

So with the help of full stop i write this to solve my problem

```
function wpc_elementor_shortcode2( $atts ) {
    $category = get_queried_object();
    $cat_id = $category->term_id;
    echo do_shortcode('[product_categories ids="$cat_id"][/product_categories]');
}
add_shortcode( 'my_elementor_php_output2', 'wpc_elementor_shortcode2');
```

Comment: If the code works then please upvote and accept the answer so others easily find the answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).